# swift: tableview returning animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to create `tableview` like on image(https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2016/05/Default-Deselection.gif) In this table view I see animation of selected row after returning to the first controller with table view.

But when I create default `tableview` in my project animation of selected row after returning to the first controller not show. How to fix it?

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 10
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "Cell%d", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)
    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.destination is ViewController) {
        (segue.destination as? ViewController)?.index = (self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Update your question with relevant code. The behavior in the gif is standard behavior of `UITableViewController`. Are you using a `UITableViewController`?.

Comment: How are you pushing the second view controller?  If you're pushing a `UIViewController` when selecting a cell, when you go back you should have that behaviour by default..

Comment: @rmaddy I use `UITableViewController` with `dynamic prototypes` and custom cell style

Comment: @joels update question

Comment: Which animation are you talking about? Is it the grey color fading out?

Comment: @GellertLee Yes. It is the grey color fading out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the selected row color to fade out after navigating back(pan the screen edge), you can use this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: @user Is the selection color not disappearing at all?

Comment: Yes selection color not disappearing

Comment: @user well that's weird. try this: add `self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = true` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: The code in this answer is not needed if the view controller is a `UITableViewController`. `UITableViewController` provides this for you automatically.

Comment: @rmaddy If I delete this code `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }` animation work. But I need this code. How to solve the problem?